# 'In person signing' with Echosign and salesforce

Tags: document, contracts

Our sales team need to be able to produce contracts off the back of opportunities within SF and present them to people in person to sign.  Ideally looking for a slick process maybe on iPads.

We currently have echosign and email out contracts from SF for signing remotely.  But this is specifically in person and the contracts can not be emailed.

I understand that you can just present the contract but apparently this can 'comprimise the digitial identity of the eSignature' as described [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hX6tAAE).  Also I am aware there is an echosign tablet app but I need this functionality from within SF to maintain workflow.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks.